# Почему картинка вставляется не на своё место? imagecopyresampled

Tags: php

У меня есть исходная картинка с возможностью её выделить(с помощью [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)). Дальше я её выделяю по координатам x1= 130, y1 = 70, x2 = 280, y2 = 220 и создаю из них уменьшенную копию, но она создаётся не по выделенным координатам, а не понятно как. Даже если вручную прописать координаты.

first.php:

```
<img src="avatars/default.jpg" id="photo" alt="">
    <form action = "second.php" method = "post" >
      <input type = "text" name = "x1" value = "" />
      <input type = "text" name = "y1" value = "" / >
      <input type = "text" name = "x2" value = "" />
      <input type = "text" name = "y2" value = "" />
      <input type = "text" name = "w" value = "" />
      <input type = "text" name = "h" value = "" />
      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" />
    </ form>
```

second.php:

```
<?php
$x1 = $_POST['x1'];
$y1 = $_POST['y1'];
$x2 = $_POST['x2'];
$y2 = $_POST['y2'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$h = $_POST['h'];
echo "x1 = $x1, y1 = $y1, x2 = $x2, y2 = $y2, w = $w, h = $h";

function resizeimg($filename, $smallimage, $xx, $yy, $w, $h)
  {
    $ratio = $w/$h;
    // получим размеры исходного изображения
    $size_img = getimagesize($filename);
    // получим коэффициент сжатия исходного изображения
    $src_ratio=$size_img[0]/$size_img[1];

    $dest_img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
         imagecopyresampled($dest_img, $src_img, 130, 70, 280, 220, $w, $h, $w, $h);

    imagejpeg($dest_img, $smallimage);
    imagedestroy($dest_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    return true;
  }
      $image = "avatars/default.jpg"; //большое фото
      $smallimage = "avatars/default_s.jpg";  // малое фото
      if  (!resizeimg($image, $smallimage, $x1, $y1, 150, 150))
         { echo  "Ошибка при создании уменьшенной копии изображения"; }else {
           echo "normasno";
         }
?>
```

Фото которое должно получиться справа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас неверное смещение, надо высчитывать по правильно формуле.

Comment: @Mully, Так в том-то и дело, что как рассчитать формулу? И почему смещение вообще возникло?

Comment: Возникло оно потому что вы формулу и не использовали). Я давненько с этим работал, надо вспоминать. Сейчас ответить точно не смогу.

Comment: imgAreaSelect какие координаты отправляется пхп скрипту?

Comment: @Mully, те же x1= 130, y1 = 70, x2 = 280, y2 = 220, а ширину с высотой по 150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что исходное изображение на сервере было больше, чем его отображение на сайте. Чтобы решить это надо было вначале отредактировать исходное изображение до размеров тех, что на сайте

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так.

```
imagecopyresampled($dest_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 130, 70, $w, $h, $w, $h);
```

Где 130 - это x1, 70 - y1, выбранное imgAreaSelect

То есть нужно просто первую верхнюю координату указать, а потом `imagecopyresampled` сам просчитает остальные точки, потому что вы передадите ширину\высоту (150x150).

Comment: Когда там сделал, то итоговое изображение, словно оказалось взято из координаты 0;0 ширины и высоты 150. попробовал прибавить эти 150 к 130 и 70. Стало чуть ближе, но не до конца